# Dynamic Quartz Configuration in Grails 3

Tags: grails, quartz-scheduler, grails-3.0

In Grails 2, we had the following block of code in our `Config.groovy` file. The `ConfigurationManagement` class did a runtime lookup in a Configuration Management Database to determine if the `quartz.autoStartup` parameter should be `true` or `false`. We also used similar configuration to load additional Quartz properties.

```
quartz {
    def autoStartupOnTheseServers = ConfigurationManagement.getValue("myApp.quartz.autoStartupOnTheseServers", "").split(",")

    if ( autoStartupOnTheseServers.any { it.trim().toUpperCase() == hostName.toUpperCase() } ) {
        autoStartup = true
    }
    else {
        autoStartup = false
    }

    // Default for clustering (jdbcStore) has to be "false" so the app will run locally.
    // Clustering (jdbcStore) will be true for DEV, TEST, QA, and PROD (set by Configuartion Management).
    jdbcStore = ConfigurationManagement.getValue("myApp.quartz.jdbcStore", "false").toBoolean()
    // don't set the props if not enabling quartz clustering...causes an exception.
    if(jdbcStore == true) { props(quartzProps) }
}
```

In Grails 3, similar code used in `application.groovy` doesn't work and there isn't any facility for conditionals that I can find for `application.yml`. Is there any way in Grails 3 to do a similar dynamic configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Grails 3, it seems that you can't set these values directly, but you can declare a local variable and use that to set the property. So, for my example above, the following works:

```
def extServerList = ConfigurationManagement.getValue("myApp.quartz.autoStartupOnTheseServers", "").split(",")
def extAutoStartup = extServerList.any { it.trim().toUpperCase() == hostName.toUpperCase() } 
def extJdbcStore = ConfigurationManagement.getValue("myApp.quartz.jdbcStore", "false").toBoolean()

quartz {
    autoStartupOnTheseServers = extServerList
    autoStartup = extAutoStartup
    jdbcStore = extJdbcStore
}
```